# Precedence of assignment = and inline rescue

Tags: ruby, operator-precedence

Using Ruby 2.3.1, I'm getting unintuitive behavior related to the relative precedence of

- assignment `=`
- inline `rescue` (so-called `modifier-rescue`)
- `raise`

This expression (1):

```
x = raise "z" rescue 2    # evaluates to 2, BUT x still has previous value
```

Behaves like (2):

```
(x = raise "z") rescue 2  # evaluates to 2, BUT x still has previous value
```

But these all work as I expected (3-5):

```
x = (raise "z" rescue 2)  # evaluates to 2, x now equals 2
x = raise("z") rescue 2   # evaluates to 2, x now equals 2
x = (raise "z") rescue 2  # evaluates to 2, x now equals 2
```

According to [this RDoc](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/doc/syntax/precedence_rdoc.html), `modifier-rescue` has higher precedence than assignment `=`. I can't see any way that (1) could parenthesize to (2) but not to any of (3-5). What's going on here?

Comment: It has higher precedence but it still only affects its immediate tokens, not something as distant as the `=` in this example. I think it's like the trailing `if` condition, it affects the entire line. Inline rescues are often trouble and best avoided, especially a blind rescue.

Comment: But why would (4) `x = raise("z") rescue 2` act differently then?

Comment: You're really into some obscure parsing quirks here. Trailing conditions like `if`/`unless` and `rescue` are special cases and I'm not sure they're as predictably intuitive as the others.

Comment: I think you might have stumbled into this bug: https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/12402 (fix merged for Ruby 2.4.0).

Comment: That certainly looks like the same issue. Nice searching.